# $2^n-1$ is composite

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

> Prove that if $n$ is composite, then $2^n$ is composite.

I tried the following:

$$2^n-1 = 2^n-1^b = (2-1)(2^{n-1}+2^{n-2} + \ldots + 1) = 2^{n-1}+2^{n-2} + \ldots + 1$$

This is the summation of $n$ numbers and $n$ is composite, hence 
$2^n-1$ is composite.

Is this correct?

Comment: Being the sum of $n$ numbers is not a guarantee of being composite, even if there is some pattern among the numbers.

Comment: [Try this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/929707/are-mersenne-prime-exponents-always-odd/929714#929714).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prove that $n$ is a prime if $2^n-1$ is a prime](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1093057/how-to-prove-that-n-is-a-prime-if-2n-1-is-a-prime)  also [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/186587/prove-that-if-2n-1-is-prime-then-n-is-prime-for-n-being-a-natural-numb) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1598170/n-2p-1-prove-that-if-n-is-prime-then-p-must-also-be-prime)

Comment: $2^n$ or $2^n-1$ ? Fix the typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any polynomial of the form $x^n-1$ has $x-1$ as a factor, since

$$
\frac{x^n-1}{x-1} = 1+x+ \dots + x^{n-1}.
$$

If $n=ab$ is composite, then we may rewrite $x=2^a$, so we have

$$
\frac{x^b-1}{x-1}=1 + x+ \dots + x^{b-1} \implies x^b-1 = (x-1)(1+x+ \dots + x^{b-1}),
$$

i.e., $2^n-1 = (2^a-1)(1+ 2 +\dots + 2^{b-1})$.

Answer (score 5):

Let us write $n=ab$ where $a,b>1$. Then 
$$2^n-1=2^{ab}-1=(2^a)^b-1^b=(2^a-1)\sum_{k=0}^{b-1}(2^a)^k$$

Because $a,b>1$, we must have $(2^a-1)>1$ and $\sum_{k=0}^{b-1}(2^a)^k>1$.